# Save JMeter response in CSV

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am new to JMeter and trying to perform a load test for the project that I am working on. 
I have created a test plan to create 2000 users. The resultant request is like below:
{
:   "Status":"200",
:   "Error":null,
:   "Content":"1858"
}
I want to save the value of "Content" for all the 2000 requests in a single csv file. 
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easy way**: append values to .jtl results file

1. Add the following line to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   sample_variables=content
   ```
2. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns that content and configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: `content`
   - Regular Expression: `"Content":"(\d+)"`
   - Template: `$1$`

   When you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) as

   ```
   jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/script.jmx -l /path/to/test/results.jtl
   ```

   and test execution finishes you will be able to see "Content" values as the last column of *results.jtl* results file

---

**Hard way**: custom scripting

1. Add a [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns that result
2. Put the following code into the PostProcessor's "Script" area

   ```
   import java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import java.util.regex.Pattern;

   String response = new String(data);

   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("content.csv", true);
   String regex = "\"Content\":\"(\\d+)\"";
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
   Matcher m = p.matcher(response);
   if (m.find()) {
       String content = m.group(1);
       out.write(content.getBytes());
       out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
       out.flush();
   }
   ```

Once test finishes you will see *content.csv* file in JMeter's working directory (usually /bin) containing all "Content" values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Dmitri.
I preferred option 2 as I want values from the CSV to be used in the next request.