# How to save response data in to CSV in Jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to save Jmeter response in CSV file. I have tried some of the answers from StackOver Flow but those are not working. 
Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this?

Note: I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31175989/12376757) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31454992/12376757).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is something not feasible when it comes to CSV files as response data can have **delimiter** characters which will break your CSV file structure. For example if you use comma as delimiter and your response data contains commas - it will be not possible to save the response into a single CSV "cell".

If you need to save the response data I would recommend using XML format of the .jtl results file for this. You can amend JMeter's default [result file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) as follows:

1. Add next lines to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
   ```
2. That's it, next time you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) as:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.xml
   ```

   the `result.xml` file will contain the response data which can be examined using either [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener or [XML viewer/editor](https://windowsreport.com/view-read-xml-software/) of your choice.

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter/)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If the response of your request can be stored in csv then you can use one of the following

1. 'Save Responses to a file' in Listeners.
2. Capture the response using regular expression extractor and write the value to a file in Beanshell code.